# mysqli query not working in foreach php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

My problem now when I click on the picture on my page, for the first time it will display. But for the second time it will display fail. This process will start by sending the data to ajax, then ajax(prosess.js) will send it to the php page(process1.php).

When I remove the code in blockquote ($query = "SELECT ...") it will run, but if not, it will display fail.

### process1.php

```
<?php

    include 'session.php';
    include 'connection.php';
    if(isset($_POST['dataS'])) {
        $table = $_POST['table'];
        $concat = "";
        $serial = $_POST['dataS'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE serialNum = '$serial'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if($row) {
            $prodName = $row['prodName'];
            $quanProd = 1;
            $priceProd = $_POST['total'] + $row['salePrice'];

            if($table == "") {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE serialNum = '$serial'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            }
            else{
                $DOM = new DOMDocument;
                $DOM->loadHTML($table);
                $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('tr');
                $check = 0;
                $check_one = 0;
                $y=0;
                function tdrows($elements,$check,$serial,$prodName,$y) { 
                    $quantity="";
                    $item = "";
                    $price = "";
                    $delete = "";

                    $x = 0;
                    foreach($elements as $element) { 
                        if($x == 0)
                            $delete = $element->nodeValue;
                        else if($x == 1)
                            $item = $element->nodeValue;
                        else if($x == 2)
                            $quantity = $element->nodeValue;
                        else if($x == 3)
                            $price = $element->nodeValue;
                        $x++;
                    }

                    **$query = 'SELECT prodName FROM product WHERE prodName = "$item"';
                    $search = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error()); 
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search);
                    $s = $row['prodName'];**
                    if($prodName == $s) {
                        $quantity++;
                        $check = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        $check = 0;
                    }
                    return $check;
                }



                foreach ($items as $node) {

                    $check = tdrows($node->childNodes,$check,$serial,$prodName,$y);
                    $y++;
                }
            }
            $priceProd = number_format((float)$priceProd, 2, '.', ''); 
            echo json_encode (
                array ( //this array is used to send the data back to ajax.
                    "success" => "1",
                    "concat" => $concat,
                    "quantity" => $quanProd,
                    "price" => $priceProd,
                )
            );
        }
        else {
            echo json_encode (
                array ( //this array is used to send the data back to ajax.
                    "success" => "0",
                )
            );
        }
    }
    ?>
```

### process.js

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("body").on("click","#product .add",
            function(e) {

                var total = document.getElementById("total").value;
                var table = document.getElementById('table-list').innerHTML;
                table = (table.trim) ? table.trim() : table.replace(/^\s+/,'');
                var serial = $(this).attr('id');
                var totalQ = document.getElementById("totalQ").value;

                if(total == "")
                    total = 0;
                else
                    total = parseFloat(total);

                if(totalQ == "")
                    totalQ = 0;
                else
                    totalQ = parseInt(totalQ);  

                var dataS = serial;
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "process1.php",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    data : {dataS : dataS, table : table, total : total},
                    dataType : 'json',  
                })
                .done(function(html) {
                    if(html.success == 1) {
                        console.log('done: %o', html);  
                        $("#table-list").html(html.concat).show();
                        document.getElementById('totalQuantity').innerHTML = html.quantity;
                        document.getElementById("total").value = html.price;
                        document.getElementById("payment").value = html.price;
                        document.getElementById('totalQ').value = html.quantity;
                        document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = html.price;
                        document.getElementById('input').value='';
                        $("#input").focus();
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Wrong serial number!");
                        document.getElementById('input').value='';
                        $("#input").focus();
                    }
                })
                .fail(function(html) {
                    console.info('fail: %o', html);  
                    alert("fail");
                });
                return false;
        });
});
```

### connection.php

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','rds');
?>
```

Comment: What shows your network sniffer in e.g. Google Chrome when you perform the second AJAX request?

Comment: This is what I got from firebug console. [image](http://imgur.com/2zold9R)

Comment: Can you show your responseText from that response? It's containing an PHP notice. That's the information we can use to solve your problem.

Comment: You mean this [image](http://imgur.com/3XObG3c) .. That image is after first click..

Comment: No that doesn't give me the information. Can you replace `alert("fail");` with `alert(html.responseText);`? What information  is in the dialog?

Comment: I got this popup [message](http://imgur.com/6SaRsvr) .

Comment: Ok good, it say your `$conn` object is null. Can you add the code of `connection.php` to your question?

Comment: Sorry late. I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

your query is wrong:try this

```
$query = "SELECT prodName FROM product WHERE prodName = '".$item."'";
```

Comment: any way the query was wrong, you have maybe other mistakes

Comment: could you post, the output of the script?I mean what is the error you get?

Comment: you can test it [here](http://pos.meximas.com/testing/main.php) .. when I click on the picture (mouse, keyboard) .. for the first time it run. but for the second time it will popup "fail"..

Answer (score 0):

According to your pictures, your problem is that your database connection isn't correct. When you execute the first request it won't do any database interaction (because off the blocknotes). The second request you will send `table` data, which will perform a query. So the first request will succeed, while the second request will give you an error on your `mysqli` (`$conn`) object.

```
if($table == "") {
    //Database interaction
    $query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE serialNum = '$serial'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

}
else{
    //No database interaction because of the blocknotes
    $DOM = new DOMDocument;
    $DOM->loadHTML($table);
    $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    $check = 0;
    $check_one = 0;
    $y=0;
    function tdrows($elements,$check,$serial,$prodName,$y) { 
        $quantity="";
        $item = "";
        $price = "";
        $delete = "";

        $x = 0;
        foreach($elements as $element) { 
            if($x == 0)
                $delete = $element->nodeValue;
            else if($x == 1)
                $item = $element->nodeValue;
            else if($x == 2)
                $quantity = $element->nodeValue;
            else if($x == 3)
                $price = $element->nodeValue;
            $x++;
        }

        **$query = 'SELECT prodName FROM product WHERE prodName = "$item"';
        $search = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error()); 
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search);
        $s = $row['prodName'];**
        if($prodName == $s) {
            $quantity++;
            $check = 1;
        }
        else {
            $check = 0;
        }
        return $check;
    }



    foreach ($items as $node) {

        $check = tdrows($node->childNodes,$check,$serial,$prodName,$y);
        $y++;
    }
}
```

Check your the username, password and database name. I'm pretty sure you used something wrong here. As mentioned in your `connection.php` file you don't use a password. Are you sure the user `root` doens't have a password? Can you access the database with a MySQL administration tool like phpMyAdmin?